# Extract text out of '<' and '>'

Tags: regex, r

I have some text inside of a span tag in an html file

I need to extract it, I tried this so far but it doesn't seem to work:

Html:

```
"<span id=\"MainContent_lblGenAssessment\">$866,250</span></dd>"
```

I tried this:

```
gsub(x = "<span id=\"MainContent_lblGenAssessment\">$866,250</span></dd>"r,pattern = ">(.*?)<",replacement = "\\1")
```

But it seems useless, How can I extract the 866,250?

**Edit**: it must use the default R libraries, I can't install any packages.

Comment: "I can't install any packages" That's extremely unlikely.

Comment: Obligatory link to canonical question on the subject: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags).

Comment: Regex should not be used on html. The proper way to do this would be to install an html parsing package and do it properly. I recommend `XML::xmlValue`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *right* way to do this is to parse the HTML with a parser, like so:

```
library(rvest)
x %>% read_html() %>% html_text()
# [1] "$866,250"
```

If you *must* do it with regex (a very bad idea if if it's for a lot of data or it's otherwise hard to inspect the result, e.g. in programmatic usage), you could do it with:

```
sub('.*>([^<]+)<.*', '\\1', x)
# [1] "$866,250"
```

If that `span` tag is in the middle of a lot more HTML, you'll have to add more regex to specify.

The regex looks for

- any character `.` repeated 0 or more times `*`,
- followed by `>`
- followed by a capturing group `( ... )`

  - containing any character except `[^ ... ]`

    - a `<`
  - repeated one or more times `+`
- followed by `<`
- followed by any character `.` repeated 0 or more times `*`,

and replaces it with the first captured group, `\\1`.

Comment: This worked, can you explain the regex please. This text is in a particular id which is unique.

Comment: @Kevin Edited to explain. It matches the whole line, but only captures what's between `>` and `<`, and replaces the whole thing with what's captured.

Answer (score 2):

try this :

`([\d,]*)<\/span>`

Assuming that every number you want to extract are inside the `<span>` tag

Comment: Error: '\d' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""([\d"

Comment: @Kevin - `\\d` in R regex.

Comment: @JanLeeYu here is the result: <span id=\"MainContent_lblGenAssessment\">$866,250</dd>" It removed the span tag, I have no clue why R does this.